# Image rotation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation, matrix-multiplication

I need manipulate matrix vert for creat a rotation in z axis.

I'm transpose this matrix and multiply for matrix rotation... Transpose again and try exclude the four column for using this in patch function.

But something seems not to work, the messagem will appear is:

??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

The problem is the patch function using a [x y z;] in the line for a plot, but for matrix rotation I'm need a matrix [x y z 1;] in the column.

```
enter code here

clf;
figure(1);
format compact 
h(1) = axes('Position',[0.2 0.2 0.6 0.6]);
vert = [1 1 -1 1; 
        -1 1 -1 1; 
        -1 1 1 1; 
        1 1 1 1; 
        -1 -1 1 1;
        1 -1 1 1; 
        1 -1 -1 1;
        -1 -1 -1 1];
fac = [1 2 3 4; 
       4 3 5 6; 
       6 7 8 5; 
       1 2 8 7; 
       6 7 1 4; 
       2 3 5 8];
theta = 30;
rotacaoz = [cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0 0;
sin(theta) cos(theta) 0 0;
0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 1];   
vertices = vert';
vertices = vertices * rotacaoz;
vertices = vertices';
vertices(:,[3 4])=[]
patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vertices,'FaceColor','c');  % patch function
axis([-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]);
axis equal;
hold on;
material metal;
alpha('color');
alphamap('rampdown');
view(3);
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product

Answer (score 1):

For a rotation matrix R and points p, the rotated points are R*p, not p*R.

Correct:

```
vertices = rotacaoz*vertices;
```